# How to avoid redundant code for static methods

Tags: java, oop, static, abstract

Let's assume I have the following classes:

```
public class Cat {
    private final String noise = "meow";

    pulic static void makeNoise(){
        System.out.println(noise);
    }
}

public class Dog {
    private final String noise = "woof";

    pulic static void makeNoise(){
        System.out.println(noise);
    }
}
```

As you can see, these two classes share pretty much the same code. To remove redundant code, I'd create a parent class like this:

```
public abstract class Animal {
    protected final String noise;

    public Animal(String noise) {
        this.noise = noise;
    }      

    public void makeNoise() {
        System.out.println(noise);
    }
}

public class Dog extends Animal{
    public Dog(){
        super("woof");
    }
}
```

Now unfortunately I'm running into a two problems:

1. Since make noise of animal can't be static anymore, as the constants
   will have to be assigned through the constructor of animal, you will
   need to create a cat or dog to get the noise of that animal. Even
   though it is a constant.
2. The method makeNoise() need's to work in the class Animal - which
   doens't have a noise per default.

A possible solution would be something along the line like this:
        public abstract void makeNoise();
which is neither allowed, nor would it erase the need to copy the code into each and everyone of the children of Animal.

How would you erase the need to have redundant code in the children of animal while keeping the method makeNoise static?

Comment: Your code doesn't compile. Unclear why you want to keep the method `static`. Unclear what you're asking.

Comment: @saka1029 Edit rejected. Don't jump to conclusions.

Comment: @EJP
The code above is a simplified version of a mathematical class. This class contains a variety of _functions_ to calculate some values.As the method makeNoise() is needed for most of these functions, I felt the need to add the modifiert static. The actual children of this class add some advanced functionality and have their own value for the constant noise:

Comment: And it doesn't compile, because your static method uses a non-static member variable. It's up to you to fix that. Not up to us to read your mind as to what is actually intended. Post is off-topic for at least two reasons.

Comment: @EJP Do not use **us**.

Comment: @EJP I'm sorry if I can't get across what I need as english is not my native language. I'm seriously having trouble to express myself :-/
 I'll try to explain some more:
I do realize tthat my second example is not working. I added it to show what I wan't to achieve.
What I want is the following: I wan't the member classes of Animal to be able to use the function makeNoise() in a static context while making use of their own constant without implementing makeNoise() in each and every member class of Animal.

Comment: I'm talking about your Java code, not your English. Code posted here is supposed to compile. Otherwise it's unclear what you're asking.

Comment: @saka1029 Why not? Are you intended to state that it *is* up to us to guess what he means? If so, you are mistaken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Static methods in Java can't be overridden in subclasses.

If you define a static method in a subclass with the same signature as the static method in the parent class, the method is not overriding the parent method is hiding it. The methods in the parent and the child class has no relation to each other.

In your example, if method `static void makeNoise()` exists in `Animal` and any subclass define the method as well, the subclass is just hiding the `makeNoise` method in Animal.

In your example, the best you can do with static methods is:

```
public static void makeNoise(String noise) {
    System.out.println(noise);
}
```

And invoke the method this way:

```
Animal.makeNoise(Cat.NOISE); // A constant NOISE is defined in each subclass
```

If the method `makeNoise` is non-static, inheritance could be used to use a different noise in each subclass:

```
public abstract class Animal {
    protected String noise;

    protected Animal(String noise) {
        this.noise = noise;
    }

    public void makeNoise() {
        System.out.println(noise);
    }

}

public class Cat extends Animal{
    public static final String NOISE = "meow";

    public Cat() {
        super(NOISE);
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, this is not what I've been hoping for, but at least I do now know the way to go. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Why would you represent a real world object behavior with a static method? Each animal has it's own behavior so you want to differentiate between them.

```
 enum AnimalBehavior {
    MEOW, WOOF, ROAR
}
```

You could use an enum which contains every animal behavior.
Also consider the following situation: A wolf keeps howling  during a full moon night. He keeps doing it until he gets exhausted. You want to track a bar which indicates the level of energy your wolf has.

```
private int energy = 100;

public static void wolfHowl() {
    System.out.println(AnimalBehavior.ROAR);
    energy = energy - 10;
}
```

This won't work technically because you're using static methods.. so keep in mind how you design your stuff since that wolf could actually howl without getting tired until someone gets really pissed off.